# vimdiff is not available as 'vim'

Tags: git, ubuntu-18.04, mergetool

On Ubuntu 18.04, `git mergetool --tool-help` results in:

```
'git mergetool --tool=<tool>' may be set to one of the following:
        araxis

The following tools are valid, but not currently available:
    bc
    bc3
    codecompare
    deltawalker
    diffmerge
    diffuse
    ecmerge
    emerge
    examdiff
    kdiff3
    meld
    opendiff
    p4merge
    tkdiff
    tortoisemerge
    vimdiff
    vimdiff2
    vimdiff3
    winmerge
    xxdiff
```

I would like to use `vimdiff` with `mergetool` but after googling I can't get it listed as 'available'.

Comment: Corrected the typo in the question, I wasn't spelling `vimdiff` wrong.

Comment: Was the next line of output going like this : "*Some of the tools listed above only work in a windowed environment. If run in a terminal-only session, they will fail.*"? Because it seems to say so in the [doc](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration).

Comment: Yes it was. I thought the ones which required a GUI were `gvimdiff`, `gvimdiff2` etc.

Comment: @RomainValeri, by "terminal-only" session, does it include for example a different tty without X? If so, I can use `vimdiff` there as a mergetool.

Comment: On my systems, `vimdiff` is just a symbolic link to `vim`.  The ubuntu ones use a crazy mess of `/etc/alternatives` sometimes but ultimately you just invoke vim *as* vimdiff to get vimdiff out of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, it turns out the answer is that `vim` is not shipped with Ubuntu 18.04 and other versions, even though I've been using `vim.tiny` for months via the `vi` command, which is in the PATH on installation.

Installing `vim` via `apt install vim` will also install `vimdiff`, among other utilities. Now the mergetool can be configured to `vimdiff`.

Comment: Here's what I get on Ubuntu 18.04:

```vimdiff

Command 'vimdiff' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install vim       
```


```sudo apt install vim
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
vim is already the newest version (2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 25 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you add the following in your `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[merge]
    tool = vimdiff
```

?

Comment: This is what I get when I run `git mergetool` after configuring `vimdiff` as the tool: `The merge tool vimdiff is not available as 'vim'`

Comment: But....that's the point of the `--tool` option : being able to use a tool *without* setting it in config.

Comment: Fair point @RomainValeri. Maybe silly question, but is vimdiff installed on your machine? I had a look at my output of `git mergetool --tool-help`, vimdiff was available, but for example `meld` was not, after I installed `meld` it became available in the list.

Comment: @padawin I think you're in fact right : I've overlooked something here with the software being installed on the system. I have to look into this. The crazy thing is.... here on a Windows machine without vimdiff I just had it in the "may be set" part of the list. And my actually configured (and VERY windowed) tool, BeyondCompare is listed under "not available".... what the hell.